# resize ipython notebook output window

Tags: jupyter-notebook

By default the ipython notebook ouput is limited to a small sub window at the bottom. This makes us force to use separate scroll bar that comes with the output window, when the output is big.

Any configuration option to make it not limited in size, instead run as high as the actual output is? Or option to resize it once it gets created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [the jupyter autoscroll extension (part of jupyter_contrib_nbextensions)](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/autoscroll), which allows you to select when the output starts scrolling in a dropdown menu (you can set it to never scroll). The API used is not officially supported though, so this may break at any time.

Comment: Thanks Matt! How do I use it?

Comment: clone repo in the right place in your ipython profile. (cf readme) copy custom.example.js to custom.js and uncomment require('custom/autoscroll.js') in it. Restart IPython.

Answer (score 310):

You can toggle the scroll window in the main menu of the notebook

Cell -> Current Outputs -> Toggle Scrolling

Comment: Or (Cell -> All Output -> Toggle Scrolling)

Comment: any way to do this on a per cell basis?  For example, cell with lots of json content want to scroll but for cell with image output would like not to scroll.

Comment: Cool, also if it is scrolling, just clicking to the left side of the output will expand it and make it non-scrolling. :-)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's much more current than the accepted answer, and it works like a charm.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I loved it.

Answer (score 46):

Addendum #2: This comment:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2172#issuecomment-53708976
indicates how you can increase the maximum size of the output cells.  Run the following code in the notebook:

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = 9999;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  In the console I get: `accessing OutputArea is deprecated. Use require("notebook/js/outputarea").OutputArea`.  Putting that in the console shows it be a function.

Comment: Didn't work for me, possibly because my output is Javascript-generated.

Comment: does't work. the output afte executing a cell is still in a scrollable area. In my case, suddenly, ipython notebook switches to scrollable panes for certain outputs, while they uses to be "normal" on beforehand. Very enigmatic...

Comment: Javascript error adding output!
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
See your browser Javascript console for more details.

Answer (score 39):

I just placed my cursor in the grey box next to the output and clicked and then all of the output was displayed.

Comment: Wow, this was such a simple solution. Why were any of the other posted "solutions" needed?

Comment: What grey box? I can't find it

Comment: @ZhanwenChen, the grey box containing the "In [x]:" and "Out [x]:" headings

Comment: @Post169 Thanks. It looks like a blue vertical strip for me.

Answer (score 33):

To resize the height of the scrollable output I do the following (you can change 44em):

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>div.output_scroll { height: 44em; }</style>"))
```

Comment: This is SO AWESOME and still works with Jupyter 1.0+

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me in Chrome.  Run it in a separate cell.  Choose the max-height you want to display without scrolling.

```
%%html
<style>
.output_wrapper, .output {
    height:auto !important;
    max-height:1000px;  /* your desired max-height here */
}
.output_scroll {
    box-shadow:none !important;
    webkit-box-shadow:none !important;
}
</style>
```

You'll still get scroll bars if the contents exceed the max-height.  There won't be a shadow box, though.  Just increase the max-height even more if really don't want scrolling at all.

Comment: I prefer this to adding an extension. I also used this method to format the rest of my output as well. Thanks, @broccoli2000!

Comment: Didn't know you could do this... bit hacky but so is the Jupyter environment in general, it seems. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For an plot.ly iplot I had to add the following to see any change (it changed all output)

```
%%html
<style>
.python-iframe > iframe {
  height:1000px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me:

```
%%html
<style>
.output_wrapper .output {
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: fit-content;
}
</style>
```

It may depend on the version of Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the options above and none of them worked. This is how I got rid of the scrolling cell.
**Right-click on the cell, and click "disable scrolling for outputs"**
I know this doesn't resize the scrolling cell, but it does make my code more legible since the scrolling cells are very small(for me at least).

Answer (score 0):

To disable scrolling for outputs in JupyterLab, simply follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the output area in JupyterLab to display the output menu.
2. From the output menu, select "Disable Scrolling for Outputs".

That's it! Your output should now be displayed without scrolling.

Answer (score -2):

In **JupyterLab** you can right click and choose:
*Create New View for Output*.