# resize ipython notebook output window with pandas dataframe output

Tags: python, css, pandas, ipython

As I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770504/resize-ipython-notebook-output-window), there is an extension for the IPython notebook, that lets you specify the number of lines that are plotted before enabling scroll bars on the output cell. This does not work for Pandas data frames, because the `div` inside the `.output_subarea` has the style

```
max-height:1000px;max-width:1500px;overflow:auto;
```

even if I set the AutoScrollLimit to `no-scroll`. How to plot the data frames always without scroll bars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was changed for 0.16.2, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements)

For ipython >= 3.0.0 will now use the notebook display controls