# Jupyter output cell collapse on multiple figures

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

For some reasons my new Jupyter notebooks seems to be collapsing the output if large figures are plotted with `matplotlib`.

Pic attached:

[image]

I want to display the pictures in full, i.e. without the scrolling bar to the right side. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [resize ipython notebook output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770504/resize-ipython-notebook-output-window)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a shortcut for that: use `o` (that is the letter o) in the command mode to expand/collapse. Or capital `O` to switch between scrolling/expanded output. See menu > help > Keyboard Shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: There is something deeper than this. I have cases where the plots generated are still not viewable even with the "expanded" output and no-scrolling. In such cases there remains a scroll bar within the output block.

Comment: That "deeper" issue is related to ipywidgets as they have their own scrolling within the output cell causing. See https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1791

Answer (score 14):

Point mouse cursor in the blank area (usually white) on the left side of the output part of the cell, then click.

Each click will toggle the status of the output area between semi-collapse and full-expand.

You can double-click to toggle between full-collapse and full-expand.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to completely disable the auto-scroll behavior in version 7 or higher. Go to **Setting** > **Settings Editor** > **Jupyter Notebook Notebook** and uncheck **Auto Scroll Outputs**.

Note, the menu item **Settings Editor** is not available in the notebook view, only in the file browser.