# .ipynb has no output in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook in VSCode. My kernal is selected as Python 3.11.4 and I have installed jupyter on it and can run it through the command prompt. However, when I try to run the notebook through VSCode, none of my cells have any visible output.

[It either looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCouJ.png)

[Or like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkjaz.png)

I have tried reinstalling Jupyter Notebook Renderer, Python, and Jupyter itself.

I also tried installing Anaconda 3 but its stuck forever at extracting package caches.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64795881/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40494645/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57829929/8508004) about options and settings to display output as collapsible (or not)  and/or toggle it in VSCode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Any updates here?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
What worked for me:

- click on the settings icon at the top-right of the notebook and
  select 'Customize notebook layout'
- scroll down to 'Notebook › Output: Text Line Limit'.
- Increase the value from 0, 30 (works fine for me).
- Restart VsCode and it should be fine now