# How to get the large output window in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When we have a large output in jupyter notebook it automatically creates scrollable output window. Is there a way we can choose width and height of window so that all of the output plots are shown in jupyter notebook?

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(range(10))
    plt.show()
```

Creates a window like this:
[image]

Can we see all the plots without scrolling?

I am aware of autoscroll nbextension, but wanted to get a large output window here.

Also, for pandas there are commands like `pd.options.display.max_rows`.
How to do this for output windows?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38704369/3135417) might be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @Abdou, I just found the answer in this link [resize ipython notebook output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770504/resize-ipython-notebook-output-window/38704369#38704369).

The original answer is by @keflavich.

I am keeping this question just for the reference purpose. It will be closed soon.

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = 9999;

# another cell
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(range(10))
    plt.show()
```

Now the output window will be large and we can see all the outputs without scrolling.

Date: Sep 26, 2018
Browser: Safari 10.1.2
Platform: OSX Yosemite 10.10

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In case somebody wants to resize the height of the scrollable output instead of removing the scroll feature:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>div.output_scroll { height: 44em; }</style>"))
```

44em is just an example

Comment: Can you clarify how to use this code? I copied/pasted in a cell, ran the command, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @HuyTruong What kind of "didn't work for me" did you get? Can you share the Error message or describe the problematic behaviour otherwise?