# How to expand jupyter notedbook cell

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am reading output of dataframe.isnull().sum() but it shows as collapsed. How can I expand the cell so that i can see all columsn NAs count. There are total 81 columsn but i am seeing only few

[image: up]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [resize ipython notebook output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770504/resize-ipython-notebook-output-window)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Setting no. of max rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424493/pandas-setting-no-of-max-rows)

Comment: What makes you think this is caused by the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in your code :

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also print the entire data frame as well:

```
print(df.to_string())
```